# Access Control from Dictionary's Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my `MainWindow.xaml`, I have a `SurfaceListBox`:

```
<SurfaceListBox x:Name="myListBox" />
```

In my Resource Dictionary (myDictionary.xaml)'s CS file (**myDictionary_CallBack.cs**), I need to do something to myListBox. How do I access it?

So far I have tried:

```
private void doWork(ScatterViewItem svi) //in myDictionary_CallBack.cs
{
    Window mainWindow = GetVisualAncestor<Window>(svi);
    SurfaceListBox myListBox = GetChild<SurfaceListBox>(mainWindow, "myListBox");
}
```

`GetVisualAncestor` returns the `Window` as expected. This is `GetChild` function:

```
public static childItem GetChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj, string elementName) where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(obj);
    DataTemplate dataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;

    return (childItem)dataTemplate.FindName(elementName, contentPresenter);
}
```

But when I tried to get the myListBox from it, it returns NULL for contentPresenter.ContentTemplate. contentPresenter itself is not NULL. Seems like there's no contentTemplate for Window.

How do I access myListBox from here?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do here, use proper DataBinding instead of a procedural approach.

Comment: @HighCore even if I use DataBinding, I still need to access the collection object (which would be assigned as myListBox's Source) in the MainWindow.xaml, no?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... managed to modify FindVisualChild in order get it working (Accessing controls in a Window):

```
public static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(FrameworkElement obj, string elementName) where childItem : FrameworkElement
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

            if (child != null && child is childItem && (child as childItem).Name == elementName)
                return child as childItem;
            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child as FrameworkElement, elementName);

                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

To use it:

```
SurfaceListBox myListBox = FindVisualChild<SurfaceListBox>(mainWindow, "myListBox");
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but ResourceDictionaries are ment to store resources. And these resources are ment to be used `by` Control-level or Window-level UI elements, and NOT the other way around. It's already very odd that you're adding a code behind file to a resource dictionary. Your approach is really wrong.

Comment: I do agree it seem very strange. I have a `Window`, which contains a num of different controls (i.e, `Image`) that is created and added during runtime in any number. To make the code cleaner, the style is written in a separate file. This `Image` in fact comes with a number of `Button` and an `InkCanvas`. To keep the code clean, I wrote the callback for these `Button` and `InkCanvas` in the dict. Otherwise, it would add another 10k lines to the `Window`'s code (not forgetting i still have alot other controls). Just that one of the function requires interaction back to the `Window`'s `ListBox`.